# angular dynamic property name in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm wondering is there any way to add dynamically generated names in nested ng-repeat, for example:

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in JSONfile">
      <div ng-repeat="i in x.name">
         <span><a ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{i.name}}</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JSONfile: returns some names,

x.name is dynamically generated from the mentioned JSONfile, and it should be used as a plain text like "NAME", if I add NAME instead of i.name I get the json file loaded, but i want it automatically loaded, because I don't know which of the names will come first.

the i.name returns this:

```
n

a

m

e
```

not "NAME" as it should..

So, the question is, is there any way to tell angular that i want this dynamically generated value to be looked as I typed it?

PS. 
`x.name` loads a JSON file with some info about a person.

If i type `ng-repeat="i in Tom"` it will return the json, but with `x.name` it doesn't work.

Thanks!

EDIT (added json):

```
var brojVijesti = [ ];
$scope.JSONfile = brojVijesti;

            // LNG Json
            $http.get("/LEADERBOARDv2/jsons/LNG.php").then(function(response) {
                var LNG = response.data.LNG;
                $scope.LNG = LNG;
                $scope.LNGbroj = LNG.length;
                brojVijesti.push({"name":"LNG", "number":LNG.length});
            });

            // DT JSON
            $http.get("/LEADERBOARDv2/jsons/DT.php").then(function (response) {
                var DT = response.data.DT;
                $scope.DT = DT;
                $scope.DTbroj = DT.length;
                brojVijesti.push({"name": "DT", "number": DT.length});
            });
```

Comment: what is json sample format?

Comment: would you mind to share JSON?

Comment: why dont you just use `x.name` why r you looping around name?

Comment: @manish : I need to get LNG, or DT, from $scope. LNG and DT and many others, are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want `i in x` not `i in x.name`

*Edit*: You can then use the [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) dependency which will grab the variable of that specific name from $scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in JSONfile">
  <div ng-repeat="i in x">
    <span><a ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{getVariable(i.name)}}</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getVariable = function(variableName) {
   //evaluate the variable name in scope's context.
   return $parse(variableName)($scope); 
}
```

Comment: I want i in x.name, because that gives a list of names for the x in the first round of a loop.

Comment: @NicoLetterman So are you trying to get the name of "DT" and then call the $scope.DT variable in order to get the list of names found in "DT"/"LNG"?

Comment: Yep, exactly, that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. :)